# Selenium via java - sendKeys doesn't send specific chars to input

Tags: java, selenium

I'm having a strange condition where i'm trying to type into input by using sendKeys , the reuslt is that specific chars doesn't seem to be implemented in the input at all.
What i'm trying to do:

```
webDriver.findElement(By.id("additionalInfo(token_autocompleteSelectInputId)")).sendKeys("(test)");
```

the result is that input field is now : test) and the missing char is '(' .
If i will try

```
webDriver.findElement(By.id("additionalInfo(token_autocompleteSelectInputId)")).sendKeys("((((((((((")
```

the result is that the input is empty.

Anyone ever faced this issue before? it is happening on a very specific input in the app, couldn't find anything related to it in the html code.
Thanks in advance.

Edit: I can manually type ( in the input field.

Comment: can you manually enter that "(" character into the field?  Perhaps it's not allowed.

Comment: i forgot to mention you can manually type '('

Comment: I've seen some funny business with selenium and sending characters. Try performing a click action into the field first, that can help.

Comment: @AlexRosenfeld I already tried clicking, not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a special character for selenium, have you tried using escape characters? Something like backslash before it if it allows it.

Edit: I found some issue report on github from last year, not sure if they agreed to not fix it. Executing a script to type "(" seems to be an alternative. 
Source: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/674

Comment: I am not familiar with escape chars for selenium, do you know what i should type? I tried backslash and it is not working

Comment: I figured it wouldn't work, was worth a shot. I guess you are stuck with the alternative only.

Comment: I guess i will have to execute JS value implementation :(

Answer (score 0):

try declaring the key as a string first

```
String keyToSend = "(test)";

webDriver.findElement(By.id("additionalInfo(token_autocompleteSelectInputId)")).sendKeys(keyToSend);
```

Comment: are you using the latest webdriver? have you tried more than one browser?

Comment: It is FF issue it seems, i have workaround for it at the moment where i replace \\( with shift key 9

Comment: ahh i ran a test in chrome and it worked, that's why i couldn't recreate

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should try using `JavascriptExecutor` as below :-

```
WebElement el = webDriver.findElement(By.id("additionalInfo(token_autocompleteSelectInputId)"));

((JavascriptExecutor)webDriver).executeScript("arguments[0].value = arguments[1]", el, "(test)");
```

Hope it helps..:)

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer , this is one workaround that i already thought to use but i wanted to see if there is some workaround without using JS